# WP7-Emulator: Object Invoked has disconnected from its clients

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I wrote some apps in C#, Windows Phone 7 (2010 Express Edition). I use Win7. The build is ok, it succeeds. When I start debugging session, the WP emulator appears and disappears a couple of time and then the program ends with the error: "Object invoked has disconnected from its client". I googled the net, search in stackoverflow, but found nothing specific (I mean C# and WP 7). 
Have anyone any idea ?

Thanks

Comment: How much ram does your PC have

Comment: can you start the application without debugging session (ctrl-f5)? can you start the emulator standalone/separate from VS, "deploy" it, and run just from the emulator ignoring VS completely? does the emulator start at all and does it run some apps like "settings" or "internet explorer"? and, finally, is it emulator of 7.0 or 7.5(mango) - or 7.8 version (if it exists) ?

Comment: For Meda : RAM : 2 G (1.6 GB usable)

Comment: For Quetzalcoatl : Can not start apps without debugging session - is the only otion in the menu; can not deploy the emulator outside VS; I have two OS options : OS 7.0 or 7.1. Like I said, I have VS 2010 express for windows phone (free from the MS site).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that, your memory is too low, the minimum requirements for the Emulator to run is at least 1.5 GB but 2 GB is recommended. Try upgrading your RAM and it should work. :)
fro here:http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpdevelop/thread/d7dee3ab-cae9-4a5e-827d-3c86ffd6afd5/

Comment: I will try; thanks for the tip. I'll let you know if it works.

Answer (score 0):

Try Building your Solution, if solution is getting build successfully (As you said),

Then Press Ctrl + F5 And let allowed Windows Phone Emulator to get fully load,
Now just try to navigate you app, and the close Emulator, and then try with F5 (Debug). It work for me

(As It may be the problem with low memory.)